# Formula behind forecast in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

Can anyone tell me the formula behind the `forecast` function in R? Preferably in the form easily understood by mathematicians (e.g  x_t, θ etc)

Here is my code in case it helps

```
suppressMessages(library(lmtest))
suppressMessages(library(car))
suppressMessages(library(tseries))
suppressMessages(library(forecast))
suppressMessages(library(TTR))
suppressMessages(library(geoR))
suppressMessages(library(MASS))
suppressMessages(library(gtools))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Model <- "choosing ARIMA"
Series.title <- "EMEA GAM<250K"
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Input.data <- matrix(c("08Q1","08Q2","08Q3","08Q4","09Q1","09Q2","09Q3","09Q4","10Q1","10Q2","10Q3","10Q4","11Q1","11Q2","11Q3","11Q4","12Q1","12Q2","12Q3","12Q4","13Q1","13Q2","13Q3","13Q4","14Q1","14Q2","14Q3",5403.675741,6773.504993,7231.117289,7835.55156,5236.709983,5526.619467,6555.781711,11464.72728,7210.068674,7501.610403,8670.903486,10872.93518,8209.022658,8153.393088,10196.44775,13244.50201,8356.732878,10188.44157,10601.32205,12617.82102,11786.52641,10044.98676,11006.0051,15101.9456,10992.27282,11421.18922,10731.31198),ncol=2,byrow=FALSE)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The frequency of the data. 1/4 for QUARTERLY, 1/12 for MONTHLY

Frequency <- 1/4

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# How many quarters/months to forecast

Forecast.horizon <- 4

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The first date in the series. Use c(8, 1) to denote 2008 q1

Start.date <- c(8, 1)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The dates of the forecasts

Forecast.dates <- c("14Q4", "15Q1", "15Q2", "15Q3")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Selects the data column from Input.data

Data.col <- as.numeric(Input.data[, 2])

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Turns the Data.col into a time-series

Data.col.ts <- ts(Data.col, deltat=Frequency, start = Start.date)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# A character vector of the dates from Input.data

Dates.col <- as.character(Input.data[,1])

#------- Transform ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Starts the testing to see if the data should be logged

transform.method <- round(BoxCox.lambda(Data.col.ts, method = "loglik"), 5)

log.values <- seq(0, 0.24999, by = 0.00001)
sqrt.values <- seq(0.25, 0.74999, by = 0.00001)

which.transform.log <- transform.method %in% log.values
which.transform.sqrt <- transform.method %in% sqrt.values

if (which.transform.log == "TRUE"){
  as.log <- "log"
  Data.new <- log(Data.col.ts)
} else {
  if (which.transform.sqrt == "TRUE"){
    as.log <- "sqrt"
    Data.new <- sqrt(Data.col.ts)
  } else {
    as.log <- "no"
    Data.new <- Data.col.ts
  }
}

#----- Find best ARIMA model ---------------------------------------------------

a <- permutations(n = 3, r = 6, v = c(0:2), repeats.allowed = TRUE)
a <- a[ifelse((a[, 1] + a[, 4] > 2 | a[, 2] + a[, 5] > 2 | a[, 3] + a[, 6] > 2),
              FALSE, TRUE), ]

Arimafit <- matrix(0,
                   ncol  = length(Data.new),
                   nrow  = length(a[, 1]),
                   byrow = TRUE)

totb <- matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = length(a[, 1]))
arimaerror <- matrix(0, ncol = length(Data.new), nrow = 1)

for (i in 1:length(a[, 1])){
  ArimaData.new <- try(Arima(Data.new,
                             order    = a[i, c(1:3)],
                             seasonal = list(order = a[i, c(4:6)]),
                             method   = "ML"),
                       silent = TRUE)

  if (is(ArimaData.new, "try-error")){
    ArimaData.new <- arimaerror
  } else {
    ArimaData.new <- ArimaData.new
  }

  arimafitted <- try(fitted(ArimaData.new), silent = TRUE)

  if (is(arimafitted, "try-error")){
    fitarima <- arimaerror
  } else {
    fitarima <- arimafitted
  }

  if (as.log == "log"){
    Arimafit[i, ] <- c(exp(fitarima))
    Datanew <- c(exp(Data.new))
  } else {
    if (as.log == "sqrt"){
      Arimafit[i, ] <- c((fitarima)^2)
      Datanew <- c((Data.new)^2)
    } else {
      Arimafit[i, ] <- c(fitarima)
      Datanew <- c(Data.new)
    }
  }

  data <- c(Datanew)

  arima.fits <- c(Arimafit[i, ])

  fullres <- data - arima.fits

  v <- acf(fullres, plot = FALSE)

  w <- pacf(fullres, plot = FALSE)

  if (v$acf[2]>0.4|v$acf[2]<(-0.4)|v$acf[3]>0.4|v$acf[3]<(-0.4)|v$acf[4]>0.4|v$acf[4]<(-0.4)|v$acf[5]>0.4|v$acf[5]<(-0.4)|v$acf[6]>0.4|v$acf[6]<(-0.4)|v$acf[7]>0.4|v$acf[7]<(-0.4)|w$acf[1]>0.4|w$acf[1]<(-0.4)|w$acf[2]>0.4|w$acf[2]<(-0.4)|w$acf[3]>0.4|w$acf[3]<(-0.4)|w$acf[4]>0.4|w$acf[4]<(-0.4)|w$acf[5]>0.4|w$acf[5]<(-0.4)|w$acf[6]>0.4|w$acf[6]<(-0.4)){
    totb[i] <- "n"
  } else {
    totb[i] <- sum(abs(w$acf[1:4]))
  }

  j <- match(min(totb), totb)

  order.arima <- a[j, c(1:3)]

  order.seasonal.arima <- a[j, c(4:6)]
}

#----- ARIMA -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fits an ARIMA model with the orders set
Arima.Data.new <- Arima(Data.new,
                        order    = order.arima,
                        seasonal = list(order=order.seasonal.arima),
                        method   = "ML")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Forecasts from the ARIMA model

suppressWarnings(forecast.Data.new <- forecast(Arima.Data.new,
                                               h        = ifelse(frequency(Arima.Data.new) > 1, 2 * frequency(Arima.Data.new), 10),
                                               simulate = TRUE,
                                               fan      = TRUE))
```

Comment: Since the same function name can be defined in more than one package, you should specify which package's `forecast` function you use (presumably `forecast::forecast`). Where in your code did you call `forecast`? What options are you using? What's the model you're forecasting?

Comment: im using forecast from forecast, and its the last command in my code. and the model is ARIMA which is also there in my code :)

Comment: but i would like a general formula for how the forecast is done if possible, my code is only there as an example :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the scrollbar at the right. I thought your code ended at `Start.date <- c(8,1)`. Silly me.

Comment: haha no worries :)

Comment: `forecast:::forecast.Arima` calls `forecast:::predict.Arima` which appears to call `stats:::KalmanForecast`... which calls C code to actually do the calculation. So it looks to me like it's writing an arima model in state space form and using the KF to predict it; this a pretty efficient way to do it. Rob Hyndman may be able to say more, if he sees this Q. I added the `time-series` tag, which might help.

Comment: thats great to know thank-you, but i really need a math formula if possible

Comment: There are prediction equations [here](http://www.etsii.upm.es/ingor/estadistica/Carol/TSAtema7petten.pdf) (from slide 12 on). Rob gives some references on state space forecasting in the help for the function itself, but if you're after a reference with a formula, I guess Brockwell and Davis (Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting) might have something nearer the equations in that pdf (it's a while since I looked at it).